# How to access child class instance attribute

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the value of 'video_mp' attribute. But is null from 'logVideoSizeChange' function.

Which is the correct way to declare the **video_mp** attribute to have access from *logVideoSizeChange* function?

**Source:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import omlBasePackage.OMLBase;
import omlBasePackage.OMLMPFieldDef;
import omlBasePackage.OMLTypes;
import omlBasePackage.OmlMP;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.util.Log;

public class LogService extends Service {

    private OMLBase oml;
    public static OmlMP video_mp;

    public static boolean logServiceIsRunning = false;

    static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyyHH.mm.ss.SSS");
    private static String timestamp;
    private static String resolution = "";

    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LogService getServerInstance() {
            return LogService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        new SetupOml().execute("startExperiment");
        logServiceIsRunning = true;
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private class SetupOml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... experimentName) {
            OMLBase oml = new OMLBase("Player", "player-exp", "exoplayer", "tcp:xx.xx.xx.xx:3003");

            ArrayList<OMLMPFieldDef> videoMp = new ArrayList<OMLMPFieldDef>();
            videoMp.add(new OMLMPFieldDef("timestamp", OMLTypes.OML_STRING_VALUE));
            videoMp.add(new OMLMPFieldDef("width", OMLTypes.OML_STRING_VALUE));
            videoMp.add(new OMLMPFieldDef("height", OMLTypes.OML_STRING_VALUE));

            OmlMP video_mp = new OmlMP(videoMp);

            // Add schema
            oml.addmp("video", video_mp);

            oml.start();

            Log.d("[LogService]", "OML Server started");

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (oml != null) oml.close();
    }

    public static void logVideoSizeChange() {
        Log.d("[LogService]", "video_mp: " + String.valueOf(video_mp));
    }
}
```

**Log results:**

`10-04 21:20:19.926 20578-20578/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/[LogService]: video_mp: null`

Comment: Where do you call `logVideoSizeChange()` method? Where do you start the `asyncTask`? Remember that `asyncTask` is an asynchronous operation, so if you type: `asyncTask.execute()` and then call the log it may not execute in that order due to the concurrency.

Comment: Thank you @piotr.wittchen for your answer. I start the asyncTask in the parent class:

In the *onStartCommand* method: `new SetupOml().execute("startExperiment");`

Comment: `logVideoSizeChange` is called from a listener:

`
  @Override
  public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees,
      float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
    // Do nothing.
    // LogService
    LogService.logVideoSizeChange(width, height);
  }
`